# Ruby on Rails 4: ActiveRecord method for join

Tags: activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4, dry

I have two associated tables, Users and Lists. This join statement works fine in all of my controller actions:

```
@users = User.joins(:lists).where(lists: {list_id: 1})
```

In my User model, I was going to do this:

```
def list_joined
     self.joins(:surveys).where(surveys: {survey_id: 1})
end
```

So that in my controller actions, I could do this:

```
@users = User.list_joined
```

But that just gives me this error:

```
undefined method `list_joined' for #<Class:0x007f93a14138e0>
```

How can I write/use a custom method in an ActiveRecord model to reuse a join? (Or can I?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You try to write class method that should looks like

```
def self.list_joined
  joins(:surveys).where(surveys: {survey_id: 1})
end
```

`self` in method definition points to class, where this definition is, `User`.

Comment: Ugh. I can't believe I didn't know how to write a class method. I guess all I've written to date were instance methods. Thanks!